# FT232RL keeps resetting

Tags: atmega328p, ftdi, ft232

I have a small board with an atmega328p and an FT232Rl. The atmega seems to be working without problems when connected to power and the programmer but when connecting the FT to usb it enters a reset loop. I tried on a few computers with different OSs and I got the same result.

Notably, when I connected it to a W10 pc without the drivers, it didn't enter the reset cycle until after installing the drivers.

Am I doing something wrong or is the chip a goner?

This is the schematic. I checked that no pins were shorting out on the board. Ignore the diode, it's not actually present.

[image: FT232RL]
[image]

Comment: You must have SMPS noise and may need to show a common earth ground on both and cable types with gnd connections in block diagram . Scope the noise levels. Or if laptop, disconnect charger or use earth gnd to all.

Comment: *without problems when connected to a programmer*...suggests a latch-up problem where FT232RL powers-up **before** ATMEGA. Perhaps you can try connecting the FT232RL's **VCCIO** (pin 4) to the ATMEGA's +5V supply instead of USB+5V?

Comment: Is reset floating? Try a cap to GND or a pullup. The programmer drives reset, so may save it from floating. Did you design and build this board or is it a commercial product? If it is a commercial product, please provide a link to whatever information is available from the maker/seller.

Comment: Why is DTR connected to reset? It seems that if the FT232 ever asserts DTR, it may cause the Atmega to reset. Try removing C15 to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @mkeith Yes it is floating. It's a homemade board. The dtr was connected to reset in our breadboard according to a ref design(don't have it with me atm) without issues but I'll try removing C15 to see if that does the trick.

Comment: @glen_geek It'll be kind of tricky in the board it's at. I'll do my best to attempt it.

Comment: Perhaps its a matter of DC supply sequencing. Try powering up the ATMEGA +5V supply **first** with no USB plugged in. Then plug in the USB and see if you get resets. The nasty sequence is when USB is powered before ATMEGA.

Comment: @mkeith C15 did it. Thank you. Apparently it was put there to allow for the atmega to be programmed through USB using the Arduino IDE. It seemed to have worked before, any clues why it was failing now?

Comment: Maybe try glen_geek's suggestion WITH C15 in place. In any event, it is good to know what is happening. Hopefully you can come up with an appropriate solution. It will be good if this question eventually gets an official answer, whether written by me or glen or you, the OP. Some people don't like it when questions get answered in the comment section. Anyway let's make sure we close it out before we all move on.

Comment: Will try @glen_geek's suggestion as soon as I can and get back with a definite answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @mkeith suggested, removing C15, severing the connection to RESET fixed the issue.

I also tried @glen_geek's of following proper DC supply sequencing and it worked, sometimes. I seem to have some noise on the board that is causing the issue. I'll test further to clean up future versions.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Given you said that if the driver is not installed it does not reset, then I would guess the fault happens after the communication is initiated.

The Reset of your MCU is connected to the DTR line of your FT232 so that also is very likely to reset your MCU as soon as you have com.

You want to check that your RX-TX signal are properly mapped on your atmega, if they are reversed in software and that you have a TX <-> TX connection, this will create a short and most likely reset your device as soon as you have communication.

And why is there a diode on U6 Rx, you won't get any data.